# Upload device's x509 certificate to Azure Iothub

Tags: go, x509certificate, azure-iot-hub

I want to upload the device's x509 certificate to iothub and create a device (on iothub) with that certificate.

I'm having trouble finding information about it and to make things worse I'm doing it in Golang with a library that tries to replicate the SDK. The lib: https://github.com/amenzhinsky/iothub

My 1st question would be, do I have/need to add my Root CA to the iothub manually?
How can I create the device (on iothhub) when trying to connect to the iothub and use/upload/import the device's certificate? (I will need to do this to multiple devices so this process has to be automated. I need to upload the device certificate when I start the real device)

The code is something like:

```
   c, _ := iotdevice.NewFromX509(iotmqtt.New(), device_id, hostname, cert)

   if err := client.Connect(context.Background()); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to iothub: ", err)
        return
    }
```

And I get a message of *not Authorized*

Comment: please share the code u tried

Comment: uploading the device certificate directly is sufficient for authentication, uploading the root CA certificate to your IoT hub for enhanced security. Navigate to your IoT Hub -> Security -> Certificates. Click "Add" and provide a name, then browse and upload your PEM-formatted root CA certificate/Use the `az iot hub certificate create` command with the appropriate parameters for the certificate name and file path.

Comment: for multiple devices use  the Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service

Comment: The code is something like what I put right now.

Comment: i raised git issue as [well](https://github.com/amenzhinsky/iothub/issues/86)

Comment: Thanks! I've done some progress in the code before that and the issue I'm having now is that the socket is closing abruptly/ unexpectedly 1006, which is not very clarifying. This only happends when I execute the code on the device. If I do it in my pc it works like a charm